# JavaScript in WebView - Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, webview, scripting

Is there a way to display of scripts JavaScript in WebView? /Android Studio

I want use WebView to display my website, but it use JavaScript.

Comment: Is it possible to provide Android's variables into Javascript of Android webView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

allow javascript in your webview:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.yourwebview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

This will enable the javascript in your webview.

Hope this helps :)